# index(of:_) method for user defined type in swift 3 is not working

Tags: swift3

```
let index = self.placeObjects.index(of:place)
```

here placeObjects is the array of type PlaceModel which is class created by myself. I am trying to get the index of an element of the same type but, it throws an error that

> Cannot invoke 'index' with an argument list of type '(of: PlaceModel)'

Comment: this is not duplicated

Comment: It is, you have to adopt `Equatable`. Or your question is ambiguous. *index of an element of the **same** type* and *array of type **Place** -> argument list of type '(of: **PlaceModel**)'* does not match.

Comment: sorry my description is wrong

Answer (score 0):

To get `index(of:)` to work, your `PlaceModel` needs to implement `Equatable`:

```
extension PlaceModel: Equatable {
    static func==(_ lhs: PlaceModel, _ rhs: PlaceModel) -> Bool {
        // determine place equality here
    }
}
```